# Using ResultSet multiple times not working as expected

Tags: java, jdbc

Why I can't while for two time.the second time I will get blank.

```
String sql = "select * from t_user";
Connection con = dbUtil.getCon();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("phoneFirst" + rs.getString("phone"));
}

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("phoneSecond" + rs.getString("phone"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because you've already consumed the result set, which is a read once type of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because, ResultSet won't work that way. It is forward only. Once it reach the end, it won't come back to first. You might want to use the Scrollable Result.

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

And once you done with a While loop, reset to first using the line `rs.beforeFirst();`

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("phoneFirst" + rs.getString("phone"));
}

 rs.beforeFirst(); 

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("phoneSecond" + rs.getString("phone"));
}
```